# Confusion in different ways of creating nodes in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, c++14, c++17

I was trying to solve merge two sorted linked list problem from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/).

I solved the problem but here's something which I'm not understanding, **When I try to create nodes and their pointers using 'new' keyword**(which stores the nodes in heap memory) **it works, but when I change it to first creating node and then creating a pointer to it then it shows *"stack-use-after-scope"***.

Here's the commented code-

```
struct ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode *next;
     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};

ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        if(l1==NULL) return l2;
        if(l2==NULL) return l1;
        
        // ListNode *res = new ListNode() works but this doesn't
        ListNode dummy(0);
        ListNode *res = &dummy;
        
        // just comparing the initial 2 values of both linked list-
        if(l1->val<l2->val){
            res->val=l1->val;
            l1=l1->next;
        }else{
            res->val=l2->val;
            l2=l2->next;
        }

        // head variable is to store the head of resultant linked list-
        ListNode *head;
        head=res;
        
        // while both list contains elements-
        while(l1!=NULL && l2!=NULL){
            // ListNode *x = new ListNode() works but this doesn't
            ListNode y(0);
            ListNode *x = &y;
            if(l1->val<l2->val){
                x->val=l1->val; 
                l1=l1->next;
            }else{
                x->val=l2->val;
                l2=l2->next;
            }
            res->next = x;
            res = x;
        }
        
        // if list1 has some elements left-
        while(l1!=NULL){
            // ListNode *x = new ListNode() works but this doesn't
            ListNode y(0);
            ListNode *x = &y;
            x->val=l1->val;
            res->next=x;
            res=x;
            l1=l1->next;
        }

        // if list2 has some elements left-
        while(l2!=NULL){
            // ListNode *x = new ListNode() works but this doesn't
            ListNode y(0);
            ListNode *x = &y;
            x->val=l2->val;
            res->next=x;
            res=x;
            l2=l2->next;
        }
        return head;
    }
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Lifetime of an automatic variable ends at the end of the scope where the variable is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic variable `dummy` is both the cause of your problem, and simultaneously unnecessary.

Merging two lists simply means crafting a node chain from the other nodes, which are already allocated. Since you have no list "wrapper" (i.e. an object that contains both the node chain and other information such as a count, tail pointer, etc), this simply because an exercise of merging the node chains, which requires a single target pointer and an enumerating pointer-to-pointer to cinch up the results.

```
ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) 
{
    ListNode *res = nullptr;
    ListNode **pp = &res;

    while (l1 && l2)
    {
        if (l1->val < l2->val)
        {
            *pp = l1;
            pp = &l1->next;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }
        else
        {
            *pp = l2;
            pp = &l2->next;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
    }

    // one of the lists will have elements left. chain that
    //  to the list-end and we're done.
    *pp = l1 ? l1 : l2;

    return res;
}
```

That's it. One thing worth mentioning. This will truly merge the two input lists. Meaning: the caller's `l1` and `l2` pointers passed as arguments aren't really worth anything anymore, and should be summarily discarded. The nodes of the original two lists are now joined into a single list that is returned as a result of this function. If you want to make a *copy* of the input lists whilst creating your merge, a different strategy is warranted, but I see no evidence of that requirement in your stated problem.

Comment: What a fine answer, You used only the existed nodes and crafted the new chain which is the sorted and combination of both. Thank you very much, Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Aadityarathore You're going to find nearly all linked data structure manipulation algorithms are all about jostling pointers; not crafting new nodes. There are times new allocations are warranted (such as making true copies), but in general you're striving for pointer manipulation to get what you want, like we did here.

Comment: I was just understanding this, just help me a bit. *pp is ultimately res initially how can we say *pp = l1 shouldn't it be *pp = &l1 because *pp and **pp both are pointers? Also is &l1->next is address of next node in l1? Apologies, I'm just getting confused as I've not used **pp(pointer of pointer) much.

Comment: pp holds the address of a pointer. if you change *pp, you change whatever that pointer points to . Honestly, easier to just see it. single-step it in a debugger and it will gel pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we'd simplify our statements here.

This'll simply pass:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
const static struct Solution {
    ListNode* mergeTwoLists(
        ListNode* l1,
        ListNode* l2
    ) {
        ListNode sentinel(0);
        ListNode* head = &sentinel;

        while (l1 && l2) {
            if (l1->val < l2->val) {
                head->next = l1;
                l1 = l1->next;

            } else {
                head->next = l2;
                l2 = l2->next;
            }

            head = head->next;
        }

        head->next = l1 ? l1 : l2;
        return sentinel.next;
    }
};
```

Since we are using a [Sentinel Node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node), we'd eventually return `sentinel.next` instead of `head`.

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got to learn something new (Sentinel node)